# Absolute script-file line-numbers in Vim-function errors

Tags: vimscript, error

When Vim reports errors within a function it typically reports relative line numbers. For example:

```
Error detected while processing function Foo:
line  11:
E123: Blah blah
```

Here indicating the issue is at line 11 *relative to start of function Foo*. Guess this is a result of how Vim load functions etc. – but is there a way to make it report absolute line numbers? As in line-number of script-file holding the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an [RFC](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/42809) suggesting this, but there was no response from Bram at the time.

Comment: I'll wait for a bit, but guess this is the answer – unless there is a clever hack.

Comment: There was no patch there, just a wish, wasn't it?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Doh.  You're right.  ZyX was doing a lot of hacking on the function code at the time, so I saw the post and just figured it had a patch.

Comment: @jamessan I remember that RFC, but I didn't completly understand what was meant so I never really tried to fix it